# Как добавить кнопку в scroll view?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно сделать активити в котором показать юзеру условия использования.

Весь текст хочу поместить в `ScrollView` и нужно сделать, чтоб когда юзер пролистал все до конца внизу появилась кнопка <kbd>Принимаю</kbd>

Но в `ScrollView` нельзя добавлять кнопки... Я придумал сделать `RecyclerView` в первой ячейке поставить `ScrollView` а во второй `Button`...

Но не уверен, что это правильное решение...

Как правильно прикрепить в конец списка кнопку?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Создай внутри `ScrollVİew` `LinearLayout` и уже все действия делай внутри этого layout'a. Ничего сложного. Сам `ScrolView` не берет больше одного элемента, но ты помещаешь LinearLayout и в него уже текст и кнопку сделай,  сработает.